# Synchronizing an ArrayList in a different Class

Tags: java

So I'm aware that in order to synchronize an arrayList you need to use

```
 Collections.SynchronizedList(new ArrayList());
```

But what if the synchronized arrayList is in one class and I want to have a refernce to it in several other classes, the multiple other classes containing the threads that will add to it. Would I do something like

```
List referenceToList = OtherClass.mainList;   
               // inside OtherClass would be List<String>mainList 
                        = Collections.sychronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
```

Or would the proper way to be

```
List referenceToList = Collections.synchronizedList(OtherClass.mainList);
```

Also is there any difference in the way i would iterate over the list, or is it the same as if All the adding and reading was contained in one Class?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter which class the list is contained in - the synchronization is for controlling access to reads and writes to that list from multiple threads (again, regardless of the class it's contained in). Once you've wrapped it in a call to `Collections.synchronizedList`, there's no point in doing it again.

For clarity (based on your question), your code would look like this:

```
class OtherClass {
    public static List mainList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
}

class RandomClass {
    public static List referenceToList = OtherClass.mainList;
}
```

Here, `referenceToList` is just a pointer to the same list that `mainList` points to, which has read/write access synchronized.

As a note, there are other `List` implementations that are designed for concurrent access situations, such as [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).